# How do I tweak WooCommerce Discount Display

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site that uses WooCommerce plug-in. When a discount is applied to a product, the cart displays the price as crossed out with the discounted price at the bottom.

I would like to have a message with the last date of the discount, something like "$100-early bird rate applies up to 2015-09-30". How would I tweak the discount display on the cart or is there a plug-in for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sale end date is stored as product meta, you can pull it using `get_post_meta` , the filter to use is `get_price_html`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'so32504214_price_html', 20, 2 );
function so32504214_price_html( $price, $product ){

    $date = get_post_meta( $product->id, '_sale_price_dates_to', true );        

    if( strstr( $price, "<ins>" ) &&  "" != $date ) {

        $date = date("Y-m-d", $date); 

        return str_replace( '</ins>', ' </ins> - early bird rate applies up to '. $date , $price );
    }   

    return $price;
}
```